# How to make this SQL line more efficient? (Case when in Partition By)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL line that looks like this

```
,SUM(Unit_Retail) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'master' THEN Master_Item WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'size' THEN Item_Number WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'color' THEN CONCAT(Item_Number, Color_Code) END) AS Sum_Unit_Retail
```

It takes a number and sums it, but the important part is partition. The user can specify the detail level that he wants.

The problem is, it takes a long time to run.

I have lots of lines like this, dealing with retail, item cost, royalty, etc.

When I change it to a simple version like

```
,SUM(Unit_Retail) OVER (PARTITION BY Item_Number) AS Sum_Unit_Retail
```

Now the whole query runs in 5 sec vs 40.

Is there any way to make that line more efficient? Or should I instead make three separate queries that check what the parameter is as the very first thing and then depending on that, I write the full query? Can anyone give me a skeleton on how to do that? I am not sure about the syntax.

Like

```
CASE WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'master' THEN 
BEGIN
...
END
CASE WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'size' THEN 
BEGIN
...
END
CASE WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'color'
BEGIN
...
```

Is that the correct way to do it? Or is there a better solution for this problem?

Comment: You are sending this SQL query from somewhere to the DBMS. From your Website or from some app you have written. Build your SQL string there (with PHP, C#, Java, whatever it is you are using) such that it is tailor-made for the desired detail level.

Comment: How does the query run if you take out/stub all of the other columns instead?  Unless this is still the same run-time, then we are going to have to see more of the query to address performance issues, because column expressions in isolation are rarely the problem.

Comment: Do all three cases take the same five seconds to complete or is it worse for one of them?

Comment: I would tailor 3 separate queries based on the input using the answer by @scsimon.  If you still think it's a problem, then you need to look at Parameter Sniffing from that same answer.

Answer (score 1):

From an efficiency perspective,

```
CASE
    WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'master' THEN SUM(Unit_Retail) OVER (PARTITION BY Master_Item)
    WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'size' THEN SUM(Unit_Retail) OVER (PARTITION BY Item_Number)
    WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'color' THEN CONCAT(Item_Number, Color_Code)
END AS Sum_Unit_Retail
```

Will you your best bet here. Without knowing the intricacies of your data, this seems to logically take the least amount of operations to complete, which is a good sign from an efficiency perspective.

If you'd like, you could compare it against your current performance by following [the steps here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53693/comparing-two-queries-in-sql-server-2012)

Comment: I think you're still supposed to sum in that final case. Probably `sum(Unit_Retail) over (partition by Item_Number, Color_Code). I doubt that concatenation is really necessary there.

Comment: Agreed, but that is what OP had, so I followed their logic.

Comment: But the `concat()` expression is part of the whole `case` and part of the `partition by`. I don't believe yours covers that as is. (Admittedly, I've had to scroll back and forth a few times to double-check.)

Comment: @JerryM.When I run my original query, it takes 45 seconds. When I ran it with no Case statements, it took about 5 seconds. Your solution takes about 20 seconds. So it is better but not great. Will separating it into three distinct queries speed it up?

Comment: for 'color' you still need sum(unit_retail) over (partition by concat(item_number,color_code))

Answer (score 1):

For us to help, we need a few things from you. Start with this blog on [*Getting Help With a Slow Query*](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/). A big thing we need is the execution plan via PasteThePlan.com

One issue you could be running into is [Parameter Sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/parameter-sniffing/). This is where the execution plan really helps see where your query is hitting performance walls.

Regarding the last part of your question, [where you created a new question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000742/sql-different-queries-depending-on-parameter)

CASE is an expression and thus isn't used to control logical flow.

> CASE can be used in any statement or clause that allows a valid
>   expression. For example, you can use CASE in statements such as
>   SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and SET, and in clauses such as select_list,
>   IN, WHERE, ORDER BY, and HAVING

For your problem, you would use [`IF...ELSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

The syntax is very similar...

```
IF @LocalDetailLevel = 'master' 
BEGIN
...
END

IF @LocalDetailLevel = 'size'
BEGIN
...
END
```