# SQL different queries depending on parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is the same but needs to change a little depending on which parameter. How can I do this?

Something like

```
CASE WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'master' THEN 
BEGIN
...
END
CASE WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'size' THEN 
BEGIN
...
END
CASE WHEN @LocalDetailLevel = 'color'
BEGIN
...
END
```

And then within each begin/end statement is a whole query with select and from and everything. 
Is that the correct way to do it?  Or do I have to use an if statement? If so, what is the syntax for that?

Also, does anyone know how the sql query will optimize for this? Will it optimize just on one of the parameters/queries?

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is an *expression* and thus isn't used to control logical flow.

> CASE can be used in any statement or clause that allows a valid
>   expression. For example, you can use CASE in statements such as
>   SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and SET, and in clauses such as select_list,
>   IN, WHERE, ORDER BY, and HAVING

For your problem, you would use [`IF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

The syntax is very similar...

```
IF @LocalDetailLevel = 'master' 
BEGIN
...
END

IF @LocalDetailLevel = 'size'
BEGIN
...
END
```

Comment: Don't you think we should cast a CV on this question because it's a dup of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57999600/6426692)? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: I didn't see that question @Sami. This one definitely spawned from that one, but the original question is more thorough